# How do you make a jar file that needs to be verified?

Tags: java, php, mysql, jar

I have been making a lot of software in Java and have all of my software as executable .jar files.  I recently came up with the idea of selling the software and will make a website with PHP, HTML, CSS, and MySQL eventually.

Anyways, I have wanted to make a system where someone buys a license to the software online and gets a registration code.  There will then be a copy of my software on the website and when you download it and run it (for the first time), it will prompt you to enter the registration code.

I want to figure out how to make a one-time prompt for the executable .jar file so that it communicates with my servers, checks the code to see if it is in one of my MySQL tables, and then sends a response back to the jar file, letting it know if the code is valid. If it is, it activates the software. I will also need to know how the user will deactivate the software if they wish to have software registered on a different computer.

If someone could show me an example or point me to a tutorial, that would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: A jar is just a zipfile with classes in it.  It doesn't "do" anything on its own.  License checking is something you'd do in your application code; it has nothing to do with the jar format.